# Convert command from SQL Server to SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite, command, declare, temp

I have this command and I want to use it at flutter sqlite but it shows error cause there is no `DECLARE` in sqlite.

```
DECLARE @totalTable TABLE 
                    (
                        id INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1), 
                        account_id INTEGER, 
                        title TEXT, 
                        account_number TEXT, 
                        client_name TEXT, 
                        total REAL
                    )

INSERT INTO @totalTable (account_id, title, account_number) 
    SELECT id, title, account_number 
    FROM Accounts 

DECLARE @counterVariable INTEGER, @startLoop INTEGER 

SET @counterVariable = (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM @totalTable) 
SET @startLoop = 1 

WHILE (@startLoop <= @counterVariable) 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE @totalTable 
    SET total = (SELECT SUM(total) FROM Bills 
                 WHERE account_id = (SELECT account_id 
                                     FROM @totalTable 
                                     WHERE id = @startLoop)), 
        client_name = (SELECT client_name FROM Clients 
                       WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(client_id) 
                                   FROM Bills 
                                   WHERE account_id = (SELECT MIN(account_id) 
                                                       FROM @totalTable 
                                                       WHERE id = @startLoop))) 
    WHERE id = @startLoop 

    SET @startLoop = @startLoop + 1 
END 

SELECT account_id, title, client_name, account_number, total 
FROM @totalTable
```

Is there a way to rewrite this command for use in sqlite?

Comment: There's also no `WHILE` or `SET` or @-variables, or `IDENTITY()`, etc.... Write the loop logic in whatever language you're using to interact with the sqlite database, and have it run the `INSERT`, `UPDATE`s and final `SELECT`.

Comment: ok you mean sqlite using just main quiries only :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking friends I found this short command for same result

```
SELECT        Accounts.id, Accounts.account_number, Clients.client_name, Accounts.title, SUM(Bills.total) AS total
FROM            Accounts INNER JOIN
                         Bills ON Accounts.id = Bills.account_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Clients ON Bills.client_id = Clients.id
GROUP BY Accounts.id, Accounts.account_number, Clients.client_name, Accounts.title
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the SQL Server code that you had. It is coincidental if you get the same results. The query in your answer could also run in SQL Server.

Comment: No it's not coincidental  I gave first SQL Server code to an expert and he gave me this command and It gave me exactly the same result. all commands works but the first not work on sqlite